# Is there a known algorithm to find groups of adjacent pixels with similar color?

Tags: image-processing

I'd like to know if this is a known algorithm with a name.

I've never done any image processing, but I'm picturing an image as a 2-d matrix of 3-d vectors (ignore transparency).

The only input parameter is distance.  Every pixel is tested against its neighbors.  If they are closer than the parameter, they join a group and their values are averaged.  As groups grow by gaining new pixels all pixels get the average value of the group.

For your typical selfie the result might resemble quantizing or posterizing, but unlike quantizing or posterizing, there is no fixed count of output colors.  If absolutely no pixels are close enough to their neighbors, the result is a 1:1 mapping of every pixel to its own group.

Is there a name for this?

Comment: I coded a simple implementation in JS using scalars instead of vectors, to get a better feel for the algorithm.  Do I need to keep coding or is there a menu option in the jungle of Photoshop that I haven't been able to find?

Comment: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00905178/file/ismm2013cqfz.pdf